# Python regex exact pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am a beginner in regex using Python, what I am trying to do is including a ppattern that has to be found exactly as it is when searching for a regex. For example `\w[$X|@]` so if `$X` is not found exactly, the match will return false instead of searching for `$` or `X`, so it would behave as follows:

google@google.com ----> matched

google$Xgoogle.com ----> matched

google$google.com ----> not matched

googleXgoogle.com ----> not matched

Comment: THe  [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `['$X'|@]` matches one of `'`, `$`, `X`, `|` or `@`. What *do* you want to match, exactly? Please show a few valid/invalid sample strings.

Comment: post updated with examples

Answer (score 1):

`[$X ...]` will match `$` **or** `X` .

you need `\$X`

if your "exactly" means match the string exactly, then you need `^\$X$`, that is, only string `"$X"` is gonna be matched.

#### Oops you edited your question... then this should work for you:

```
In [3]: import re
In [4]: l=['g@g.com','g$Xg.com','g$g.com','gXg.com']         

In [5]: for s in l:                                 
    print s + " matched? " + str(True if len(re.split('\$X',s))>1 else len(re.split(r'[$X]',s))==1)
   ....:     
g@g.com matched? True
g$Xg.com matched? True
g$g.com matched? False
gXg.com matched? False
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: question was updated with examples, so I added one to the answer.

If you want to search for `$X` in text, here is a quick example of what you might do:

```
import re

pattern = r'\$X|@'
m = re.search(pattern, "google$Xgoogle.com")
```

Then if you are in a function you can do:

```
if m:
    return True
else:
    return False
```